# even numbers in mathematica

Tags: combinatorics

I want mathematica to produce a list of all the 5-digit EVEN numbers without leading zero and all 5 digits must be different. So 37602 is ok but 03872 is not.
Does someone know how to instruct Mathematica to do so?

Thanks anyway,

Max 
Holland

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, but here's one:

```
Select[Range[10000, 99999, 2], Max[DigitCount[#1]] == 1 &]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not compute them directly?
For the last digit you have 5 options. For the next-to-last you get 9 (all except the one already used), then 8, then 7. The first digit is a bit tricky, it isn't just one of the 6 remaining cases, you must exclude the case that it is 0. So you need to count how many of the numbers start with 0. By the same sort of reasoning (reserve 0 for first position, count the numbers of 4 digits ending in even), this gives $4 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ In all:
$$
5 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 - 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 13776
$$